# purpose of <bean> in applicationContext-security.xml

Tags: spring-security

Newbie question... what is the purpose of the bean that is defined before the actual security settings in applicationContext-security.xml?

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">
```

Comment: Both of them really, the whole block of code.

Answer (score 1):

Because this file is the one going to declare the configurations of spring security. If you have custom implementations then you have to inject those as beans. This is not relevant to the default configuration but for the custom implementation. for more details of custom implementation follow this.

http://malalanayake.wordpress.com/2014/06/30/stateless-spring-security-on-rest-api/

Answer (score 1):

This root tag allows you to omit the `security:` prefix (standard, you could use anyone) within your file. For example, you'll write:

```xml
<http use-expressions="true">
    <http-basic />
    <headers />
    <remember-me services-ref="rememberMeServices" />
</http>
```

Instead of:

```xml
<security:http use-expressions="true">
    <security:http-basic />
    <security:headers />
    <security:remember-me services-ref="rememberMeServices" />
</security:http>
```

On the other hand, you'll have to write:

```xml
<beans:bean id="rememberMeServices" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices">
    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"/>
    <beans:property name="alwaysRemember" value="true"/>
    <beans:property name="key" value="${rememberMe.key}" />
</beans:bean>
```

Instead of:

```xml
<bean id="rememberMeServices" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"/>
    <property name="alwaysRemember" value="true"/>
    <property name="key" value="${rememberMe.key}" />
</bean>
```

**To sum up**, this *locates* the file in the `security:` namespace rather than the `beans:` one (for example).

Answer (score 1):

The `beans` [root element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element) tells the XML parser about content of the document.

It does so by referring to different [namespaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace) (the attributes with `xmlns` prefix) which will be used in the document. Each of them can define what elements will be allowed in the document and how to validate it.

The `xsi:schemaLocation` advices parser on where to find the definitions ([XML schemas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_schema)) for each of the namespaces, so that it can use it for validation.

The prefix in the `<beans:beans>` denotes to which of the namespaces does the element belong to. Each XML document can declare multiple namespaces and this helps the parser to tell which one is the element part of.